# Sorting Arrays at the third Dimension

Tags: php, arrays, json, steam-web-api

I try to sort this Array by the name but the function i wrote dont work

```
{
"response": {
    "game_count": 175,
    "games": [
        {
            "appid": 4000,
            "name": "Garry's Mod",
            "playtime_forever": 4040,
            "img_icon_url": "4a6f25cfa2426445d0d9d6e233408de4d371ce8b",
            "img_logo_url": "93c9364c3942223ab66195182fe1982af8a16584",
            "has_community_visible_stats": true
        },
```

Sorted by the name, which is at the third level

i tried:

```
function val_sort($array,$key) {

foreach($array as $k=>$v=>$g){
    $b[] = strtolower($v[$key]);
    }
SORT_ASC($b);
foreach($b as $k=>$g=>$v) {
    $c[] = $array[$k];
}

return $c;
}
$sorted = val_sort($array, 'name');
```

But this didnt work for me.
I hope you can help me ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a foreach in combination with usort:

```
foreach ($yourArray["response"] as $key => &$subarray) {
    usort($subarray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['name'] <= $b['name'];
    });
}
print_r($yourArray); //now it's sorted
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast Answer! It worked but i had to switch function($a, $b) to function($b, $a). It was sorted in the wrong way so yea

Comment: Glad i could help, you also could change <= to >=